# Knockout Json Nested Children - Changing Select Menu to Radio/Checkboxes

Tags: jquery, json, knockout.js

I have a working version of knockout code in which I'm using a parent select menu to determine what the child values should be.

Here's the example:
https://jsfiddle.net/mujaji/6zk5crn8/2/

What I'm attempting to do is turn the parent level to a radios and the child level to checkboxes.

Here's what I've tried:
https://jsfiddle.net/mujaji/tju15joe/4/

```
function ViewModel(items) {
    this.levelOne = ko.observableArray(items);
    this.selectedLevelOne = ko.observable();
    this.selectedLevelTwo = ko.observable();

    function getById(items, value) {
        if(!value) {
            return [];
        }

        var result = ko.utils.arrayFirst(items, function(item) {
            return item.value === value;
        });

        return result && result.childItems || [];
    }

    this.levelTwo = ko.computed(function(){
        var items = this.levelOne();
        var id = this.selectedLevelOne()
        return getById(items, id);
    }, this);

}

var items = [
{text: "Marvel Superhero", value: "1", childItems: [
    {text: 'Captain America', value: '01'},
    {text: 'Ironman', value: '02'},
    {text: 'Wolverine', value: '03'},
    {text: 'Nightcrawler', value: '04'},
    {text: 'Spiderman', value: '05'},
    {text: 'Hulk', value: '06'},
    {text: 'Thor', value: '07'},
    {text: 'Hawkeye', value: '08'},
    {text: 'Silver Surfer', value: '09'},
    {text: 'The Thing', value: '10'},
    {text: 'Mr Fantastic', value: '11'}
]},
{text: "Marvel Villian", value: "2", childItems: [
    {text: 'Dr. Doom', value: '01'},
    {text: 'Magneto', value: '02'},
    {text: 'Juggernaut', value: '03'},
    {text: 'The Blob', value: '04'},
    {text: 'Galactus', value: '05'}
]},
{text: "DC Superhero", value: "3", childItems: [
    {text: 'Superman', value: '01'},
    {text: 'Batman', value: '02'},
    {text: 'Robin', value: '03'},
    {text: 'Wonder Woman', value: '04'},
    {text: 'Raven', value: '05'},
    {text: 'Aquaman', value: '06'}
]},
{text: "DC Villian", value: "4", childItems: [
    {text: 'Lex Luthor', value: '01'},
    {text: 'Joker', value: '02'},
    {text: 'Grundy', value: '03'},
    {text: 'The Riddler', value: '04'},
    {text: 'Lobo', value: '05'}
]}
];

var module = {};

module.sampleViewModel = new ViewModel(items);

ko.applyBindings(module.sampleViewModel, document.getElementById("override-more"));
```

Does anyone have any advice on converting from select to radio/checkbox?

Is there a better way to do what I'm attempting?

Comment: How do you want the checkboxes to actually work? You are binding them against a single observable, do you want them to look like checkboxes but still function like radio buttons? Or do you want them to function like a mutli-select: adding all the checked values into an array?

Comment: Ah! I see what you mean. Ideally, I'd like add all checked values into an array

Comment: here's the updated fiddle with the radio resolved: https://jsfiddle.net/mujaji/tju15joe/5/

Comment: To further explain my intention... if a parent radio is chosen, show the children as checkboxes of the selected radio

Comment: See my updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `foreach` bindings, you are creating a new binding context (you might also have heard it called "scope"). You need to make sure to use `$parent` or `$root` when stepping back up.

You have a binding for radios that looks like this

```
<input type="radio" name="firstLevel" data-bind="checkedValue: value, checked: selectedLevelOne">
```

The problem is `selectedLevelOne` is on the parent. You can fix this binding like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="firstLevel" data-bind="checkedValue: value, checked: $parent.selectedLevelOne">
```

That will solve the radio buttons. The checkboxes are a different issue, since you are asking for multiple selections. Here, you can use the [array-binding behavior of](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html) the `checked` binding

```
<input type="checkbox" name="nextLevel" data-bind="checked: $parent.selectedLevelTwo, checkedValue: $data">
```

Here is a [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tju15joe/8/), showing the radio button selection, and checkboxes populating an array.

One problem is that when the parent radio is changed, the child selection array wont automatically updated. One way to solve this is with a subscription (this is in the fiddle).

```
this.selectedLevelOne.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    this.selectedLevelTwo([])
}.bind(this))
```

Comment: so I the portion that was missing was 'checkedValue: $data'??

Comment: You were also missing the `$parent` bit

Comment: @JosephSjoblom I updated the fiddle with a minor bugfix for changing the radio

Comment: quick question, I want to make a selection on load and display the text of the selection. I have it working, but it's giving me the value, not the text: https://jsfiddle.net/mujaji/tju15joe/9/

Comment: That's because you are binding against the value. You can bind against the object if you want. Check this fiddle out. https://jsfiddle.net/tju15joe/10/. If you need an explanation of this, please ask another question

Comment: Hey @Tyrsius - here's an real-world example where I'm using three levels (hiding the first level on load), but the selectedLevelOne text doesn't seem to be populating/computing:
https://jsfiddle.net/mujaji/qL9343m4/4/ 

Oddly enough, I'm not getting an error either. Everything else seems to be working fine. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are confusing the object and value level. You set the value to `10` on load, but the `text` binding is `selectedLevelOne().text`. Its written as if you will bing against an object with a `value` and `text` prop. The number `10` has neither of these properties. The rest of your code correctly treats `selectedLevelOne` as if it will contain the value directly, instead of an object. This appears to be a systemic confusion on your part. You need to decide whether these observables will hold values or objects, and then write all of your code against that decision.